# Prove that U = $\{z| 0 < |z| < 1\}$ is a domain

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

First I want to prove that for all Z $\in$ U, z is an interior point. I have that the definition of an interior point is that there is a neighborhood of $z_0$ that contains only points of U. I feel like you start by dividing the distance from some point then proving it is in the set, but am unsure how to write this in a proof.

Next I want to prove that U is connected by showing there is a polygonal line r(t) starting at $z_1$ and ending at $z_2$ that lies entirely in U. I am not sure where to start for this proof.

Comment: Can you clarify which set you mean? I believe there is a symbol missing between $0$ and $|z|$.

Comment: Did you forget a $<$ in your definition of $U?$

Comment: Why does it need to be a polygonal line? Polar coordinates make it much easier to find a path…

Comment: Start by drawing a picture of $U$.  If you do not know "where to start", this would be it.

Comment: try comparing the magnitude of $z$ with $\inf\{d(z,x): x\in\partial U\}$ by drawing a picture. for path connectedness, use arcs